# The stretch factors of $A^T A$ are the eigenvalues of $A^T A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, symmetry

Why are the stretch factors of $A^TA$ equal to the eigenvalues of $A^TA$? I understand that $A^TA$ is a symmetry matrix and have proved that the stretch factors of $A$ are square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. But why is it true that the stretch factors of $A^tA$ are the eigenvalues of $A^T A$?

Any verification would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stretch factors of $A^TA$ would be the square root of the eigenvalues of $(A^TA)^T(A^TA)$.

If $A^TA = UDU^T$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $U$ is orthogonal.

Then $$(A^TA)^T(A^TA)=UDU^TUDU^T=UD^2U^T$$

Hence eigenvalues of $(A^TA)(A^TA)$ are the squares of eigenvalues of $A^TA$.

Comment: Thanks. Get that now.

Comment: $A^TA=UDU^T$, from there we have $(A^TA)^T=UDU^T$ (it is symmetric).  Also note that $U^TU=I$ the identity matrix.